# How to Scale Up a div on hover and Scale Down all other divs

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, jquery-selectors, hover

I've been trying to figure this out forever now but without success.

Below are 6 circular divs.  When a user hovers over one of them, I want the hovered div to expand a bit (scale up) and all other divs to shrink a bit (scale down).

I tested the following:

```
#container div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#container div:not(:hover) {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

However, this keeps all the divs scaled at 0.9 (I want them to only shrink when one of the other divs are hovered.

I also tested the following:

```
#container div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#container:hover div:not(:hover) {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

However, since this shrinks all the divs when the entire container/parent element is hovered, not the individual divs, this solution doesn't work either.

Basically, when a circle (and only that circle) is hovered, I want it to expand and all others to shrink.

I'd very much prefer a pure CSS solution but I'm open to jQuery.
[image]

I also have attached a jsfiddle, this is why using hover on a container doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/e5vjL7k7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make class to `scale-up` and `scale-down` and on hover and add scale-up class to element that is hovered and scale-down class to its siblings.

```js
$("li").hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('scale-up').siblings().toggleClass('scale-down')
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
}
.scale-up {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.scale-down {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I can't use display: flex, I need to have my divs as "inline-block" and centered (refer to my attached image).

Answer (score 1):

Try this using only HTML/CSS:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="target"></div>
    <div class="target"></div>
    <div class="target"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.target {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px;
}
.container {
    float: left;
}
.container:hover .target {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
.container .target:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4f335nty/1/)

Edit: Added easing

Comment: Thanks, but using a container was exactly the thing I was trying to avoid. Because my container is large and my divs are circles, this doesn't work (see my image)

Comment: Well it has to sit inside of something yeah? This is just jsfiddle example of how the actual code works. There is no reason this shouldn't work? Regardless of form factor of container and div shape? Plus, you have container in your example code? lol. You had never stated you didn't want a container.

Comment: I have a container, but here, you notice how they shrink before you hover over onto the div? In your example it's hard to see because they are rectangles, but in my case, applying hover on the container makes the divs shrink even when not hovered: https://jsfiddle.net/e5vjL7k7/

Comment: Ok, I see what your issue is with this.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to go with the jquery answer provided since I have a clear understanding of the issue with the container.

Comment: It looks good, but unfortunately it requires the display to be "flex", and I need mine to be inline-block

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'll keep working and if I figure it out I'll send you the solution.

Comment: With just CSS? I'm interested. I got it to work with jQuery, but not CSS.
https://jsfiddle.net/e5vjL7k7/1/

Comment: Unfortunately no, I used Nenad Vracar's solution

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm quite late to the party but the new `:has` relational pseudo-class is perfect for this, in combination with `:not`

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.target {
    width: 100px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.container:has(> *:hover) > *:not(:hover) {
    transform: scale(0.9);
}

.container > *:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

You can be more specific with your selector, but honestly you could add any number of completely different items to the container and avoid selecting them explicitly to have them treated the same

As of writing this, `:has` is supported by the latest versions of most major browsers, however global support is just shy of 90% so I'd either use a fallback or avoid it until it's adopted globally